# Best way for Uploading a large audio file max of 200mb to server via webservice?

Tags: android, web-services, audio, file-upload

I need to upload a large audio file max of 200mb to server via webservice. Reading the whole file to runtime memory will be a real pain, i hope so.
 So i think the best way is to stream this file and upload it to server like we do with RandomAccessFile. Can anyone tell me, is this a possible way? If not how can we
tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, but because of the many events that can stop an upload, instead of synching a file, I decided to write an app that looks for these types of files (by extension or within a specific folder) and upload them via ftp.
On the Server side I have a similar process that looks for files uploaded and then process them.
All this requires code that exists everywhere here in Stackoverflow.

Hope this helps.